# Show what's outside scrollview's bounds

Tags: ios, scrollview, paging

How is it possible to show what's outside scrollview's bounds?

I created a scrollview with certain bounds, set the content size several times bigger in y axis, enabled paging, but would like to show one page above and one below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `@property(nonatomic) BOOL clipsToBounds` to `NO` for your scroll view instance.

Comment: This is correct. Note, however, that your scrollview won't get touch events outside of its own bounds, even if the content is not clipped.

Comment: Thanks! Is is it also possible to set the size of the visible area? And how then could I expand the touch area, but keep the paging my desired size?

Comment: You'll need to put your scroll view inside other view that vill make the clipping.

Comment: Any ideas how to get touch events outside scrollview's bounds? I want to show more than one page, but at the same time enable the user to be able to scroll anywhere. My page views are pretty small, that reduces the interaction area greatly.

Comment: It looks like you'd better use http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html